# How to traverse all columns of type Choice with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to traverse all columns in one list of type choice only, I really know how to iterate over a list, and even on columns, but I only need to see choice columns in my script

any idea?

Comment: Si se puede hablar en castellano en este foro que significa traverse? you mean to iterate through the elements of the choice column?

Comment: traverse=iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not powershell but C# SP client object model equivalent fragment for some list 'list':

```
foreach (Field f in list.Fields)
{
    if (f.TypeAsString.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("CHOICE"))
    {
        FieldChoice fc = (FieldChoice)f;
        string[] choices = fc.Choices;
        ... do something with choices...
```

I do not like the 'stringly' typed object above but this works.